# Move child view and parent view should also scroll

Tags: android, kotlin, scrollview

> [image: enter code here]

I am trying to move the blue box as shown in the image and It's working fine but the issue comes when I need to scroll its parent view as well either on left or right as per the blue box direction.

Below is the sample code. It has horizontal scroll view and has child as recyclerview and relative layout

```
<HorizontalScrollView
           android:id="@+id/hsvMeasure"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp20"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp8"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:measureAllChildren="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/clAddRemove"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fl_measure"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp20"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp8"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/clAddRemove"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_measure"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp8"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp8"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp8"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="visible" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_count_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp2"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp2"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp16"
                android:visibility="invisible" />


            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/flHarmony"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/beatHeight"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_count_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp8"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp8"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp8" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

enter code here

Comment: add some xml code, mention what you're doing and what should be expected result.

Comment: Please check the added code

Comment: try to disable nested scrolling for recyclerview, android:nestedScrollingEnabled=false

Answer (score 0):

You didn't implement any source code. That's why I am able to tell you what to do.
You should try coordinator layout.
`https://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout`

Comment: @AmanpalSingh I understand what is wrong right there. You are trying to scroll the whole layout. But, you can't scroll directly by `HorizontalScrollView` or `VerticalScrollView` or `NestedScrollView`. Cause, You had implemented a `recyclerView` right there. So, you have to use `coordinatorlayout`. You have to re-edit the whole code. Try the following link
[Coordinator Layout](https://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout)

Comment: @AmanpalSingh there's lot of git on that link and lot of source code. You have implement them(only source code) in your source code.

Comment: Do you mean to say that I need to add recyclerview and relativelayout inside coordinator layout?

Comment: @AmanpalSingh yes! Cause, I earlier thought that `NestedScrollView` could work. But, when I was doing that in a program I notice that actually don't work. So, a person advised me to implement `coordinator layout` there's no other way to done the work.
I hope it will work for you also.

Happy Coding